# Setting Content Disposition using Rackspace Cloud Java APIs

Tags: rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

I am using Java Bindings for Rackspace Cloud API

I am trying to figure out how to set content disposition for the file that I upload to rackspace

I do not see a straightforward way of doing this through FilesClient object exposed through this API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java API does not provide this functionality out of the box

I ended up changing the FilesClient.saveObjectAs function

-- added a String parameter as "contentDispositionValue"
-- the code that constructs the request, adds this parameter to a set of request parameters